# How to pass a mutable function parameter as argument to another function?

Tags: rust

Why does Rust prevent this code from compiling, with the error: "cannot borrow immutable local variable `arr` as mutable"? How to pass the vector into another function as mutable reference?

```
let mut vec = vec![0];

fn bar(vec: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    // some code here
}

fn foo(vec: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    bar(&mut vec);
}

foo(&mut vec);
```

Comment: related: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/36542 -- my error was `cannot borrow as mutable, consider changing this to be mutable`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to use `&mut` in this case:

```
let mut vec = vec![0];

fn bar(vec: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    // some code here
}

fn foo(vec: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    bar(vec);
}

foo(&mut vec);
```

because `vec` is already a `&mut Vec<i32>`.